Switching for raster to terra package in R - netcdf file with 4 dimensions
I have a netcdf file with 4 dimensions (time, longitude, latitude, level). Previously when using the raster package in R, I used brick("file_page",level=2) to select the level. But this doesn't seem to exist in terra. What is the equivalent in terra?
When I try to load the raster in terra it seems to combine the time and the level dimensions. Basically, I had 320 time steps and 10 levels. When I load the raster in terra, it makes a raster with 3200 levels. How do I just load a raster with one level (of 10) and 320 time steps?

Welcome to SO. Please add the code you have used and also provide a way to reproduce the problem, which could easily be due to the data having issues

You should be able to do that like so:
library(terra)
r <- rast("file_page", 2)

Or
s <- sds("file_page")
lev2 <- s[[2]] 


The first option doesn't work. The resulting "r" still has 3200 levels. The second option gives the error: Error: [sds] file has no subdatasets.
